# 400 status code when pulling US Census API

Tags: python, pandas, api, beautifulsoup, census

I want to use the census API to pull employment data that is identical to the CB1100A11 table (Screenshot attached).  Each row of this table represents a different 2-digit NAICS sector.  Although structuring this table is another task entirely, it appears that I am unable to get API data when I include additional variables.

I have had success with each of the [*example urls*](https://api.census.gov/data/2011/cbp/examples.html) the Census Bureau provides, but I have not had any success with my own.  I have included a code snippet below, minus my key, to show what this looks like.  I am using Python 3 in Jupyter Notebooks and BS4 from BeautifulSoup.

I have already consulted the [API users documentation](https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/data/developers/api-user-guide/api-guide.pdf) and [variable list](https://api.census.gov/data/2011/cbp/variables.html) without success.

```
example_vars = 'NAICS2007_TTL,GEO_TTL,EMP,LFO_TTL,ESTAB,PAYANN'
my_vars = 'NAICS2007,NAICS2007_TTL,GEO_TTL,EMP,LFO_TTL,ESTAB,PAYANN'

county_fips = '027'
state_fips = '42'
key ='str'

url= 'https://api.census.gov/data/2011/cbp?get='+my_vars+'&for=county:'+county_fips+'&in=state:'+state_fips+'&key='+key

res = requests.get(url)
res.status_code
```

When I add additional variables like `NAICS2007` I receive a status code 400, but when I use the example variables I get a 200.  The common denominator seems to be my code.  Can anyone help?

[image of the CB1100A11 table](https://github.com/CarbonCriterium/img/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202019-07-23%20at%2010.15.01%20AM.png)

Comment: Kind of difficult to answer this question because it seems to be an issue on the API itself. I'm thinking that you should remove ```NAICS2007_TTL``` in ```my_vars```.

Answer (score 0):

This should be moved to comments (I can't comment bc of rep) but as someone who's worked closely with the US Census API I **highly** recommend using the Census library:

https://github.com/datamade/census

One of my queries looks like this (where acs1dp is the database I am querying):

```
    from census import Census 

    conn = Census("MY API KEY")

    name = 'NAME'
    agriculture = 'DP03_0033PE'
    laborForce = 'DP03_0003PE'
    travelTime = 'DP03_0025E'
    highSchool = 'DP02_0066PE' 
    unemployed = 'DP03_0009PE'
    poverty = 'DP03_0128PE'

    payload = conn.acs1dp.get((name, travelTime, agriculture, poverty, 
    unemployed, laborForce, highSchool), {'for': 'state:*'})
```

which returns each of those column values for all of the states.